# Jenkins EC2 plugin previous versions

Tags: plugins, hudson, amazon-ec2, jenkins

Does anyone know how to revert the current Jenkins EC2 plugin back to older versions? I have looked under plugin management but for this plugin they don't give the option of going back to previous versions so I am wondering do I have to download an .hpi file somewhere and manually install?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have access to the old version of the plugin's .hpi file, you should be able to:

- Stop Jenkins
- Move aside the current HPI file and its associated subdirectory (these will be under $JENKINS_HOME/plugins)
- Move the older HPI file into $JENKINS_HOME/plugins
- Start Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

Here is a place to see and dowload the hpi file for [Previous Amazon EC2 Plugins.](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/ec2/)